# How to convert Viewdata to model object in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Question where i need to convert my Viewdata data to model objects in View

model:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public ProductModel()
    {
        Category = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Category.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Books",
            Value = "1"
        });
        Category.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Mobiles & Tablets",
            Value = "2"
        });
        Category.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Laptops & Accessories",
            Value = "3"
        });
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }        
    [RegularExpression(@"^\$?\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$")]
    public decimal BasePrice { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ProductHtml()
{
    ProductModel model = new ProductModel();
    Viewdata["VD"]=model;
    return View(model);
}
```

So that I can bind the values like below.

**So how can I convert my `ViewData` values to model objects here and bind**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.Category, "--Select--")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)
```

Is this possible in MVC to achieve ?

Comment: Why would you put your model into ViewData at all? Just pass it to the View as you have in your `return` statement. Set the model on your page, and you're good to go.

Comment: Agreed with krillgar - the "right" way to do this would be to put your Category and Descriptions into your model in the ProductModel() method. Then your code for your view would work just the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this,

```
public ActionResult ProductHtml()
{
    ProductModel model = new ProductModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.Category, "--Select--")
```